# Entity Framework DBSet is extremely slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm following a n-layered pattern with a services layer. No repository layer. The tutorial is http://techbrij.com/service-layer-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-unit-testing . My problem here is the `GetAll()` method here is absurdly slow. It is taking 12 seconds to run a simple paginated query. It seems to be an issue with EFs `DBSet`, being retrieved by using the `_context.Set<T>()` method

My EntityService

```
public class EntityService<T> : IEntityService<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    protected GraphicContext _context;
    protected DbSet<T> _dbset;

    public EntityService(GraphicContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbset = _context.Set<T>();
    }


    public virtual async Task CreateAsync(T entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        }

        _dbset.Add(entity);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public virtual async Task<T> FindAsync(params object[] keyValues)
    {
        if (keyValues == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("id");
        }

        return await _dbset.FindAsync(keyValues);
    }

    public virtual async Task UpdateAsync(T entity)
    {
        if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        _context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public virtual async Task DeleteAsync(T entity)
    {
        if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        _dbset.Remove(entity);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbset.AsEnumerable<T>();
    }
}
```

It is using `DBSet` because after some research `IDBSet` is obsolete and was also slow on us.

The table we are accessing has about 300,000 records, but we are using pagination to help the query and for ease of access for the user. Anyways, To test that it was the call to `_context.Set<T>()` that is being slow I skipped the service and ran my context in the controller to run the exact same query. The query took less than a second.

Does anyone know why this would be this way or have a way to speed this up? I'm thinking I may have to avoid using the set() method. Any other alternatives to this?

Comment: The issue is not the `DbSet`, but `AsEnumerable`. And in general the `IEnumerable<T>` type of the result of `GetAll`. This way you'll always read the whole table in memory and run queries against memory with LINQ to Objects.

Comment: I actually removed the `AsEnumerable<T>()` and replaced it simply with `NoTracking()`. It sped up the query by 3 seconds. It still took about 8 or 9 seconds to run

Comment: But you need also to change the `GetAll` type, otherwise the effect is the same as with `AsEnumerable` call. e.g. use `IQueryable<T> GetAll`

Comment: @IvanStoev: That is not correct. `IEnumerable<T>` as the return type - and also the call to `AsEnumerable` - won't execute the query. But it is correct that all following LINQ calls will work on the in memory objects. Still, the query will not be executed until the `IEnumerable<T>` is actually being enumerated, e.g. in a loop or by a call to `ToList`, `ToArray` etc.

Comment: Perfect! That's what it was! Answer my question and I will mark yours as correct

Comment: So, I assume that you didn't perform a clean test but did in fact call other LINQ methods on the result of `GetAll`?

Comment: I'm trying to speed up my query. There are other LINQ methods on the `GetAll`, however they are not the problem. Like I said I tested it by injecting the context into the controller and replacing my service method with that. It actually was faster that way(1sec compared to 8-12), but of course we don't use the context in our controllers.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I'm not saying it will execute it immediately. But the point is that further queries (when materialized) will effectively load the whole table in memory.

Comment: @IvanStoev And that is absolutely correct. What I was getting at is this: Calling `GetAll` will be no different in performance, no matter if you use `AsEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` or if you use `IQueryable<T>`. The performance will be exactly the same *for calling that method*.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth That makes sense. This is being implemented as a service layer so it will mostly have some kind of LINQ methods attached. I'm kinda surprised that, knowing that, they didn't have it as an `IQueryable` in the tutorial for it.

Comment: @TaylorMitchell As far as I understand the tutorial, that method is really meant to retrieve all entities - hence the name. The usage also supports this assumption. It was never meant as a starting point for queries.

Comment: gotcha. That's what I started thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the result type of `GetAll` is `IEnumerable<T>`, all the queries against the result will cause loading the whole table in memory and then querying it via LINQ to Objects.

If you want your queries to be executed at the database (i.e. via LINQ to Entities), remove `AsEnumerable()` call and change `GetAll` type to `IQueryable<T>`:

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
{
    return _dbset;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. And sorry for the last comment, it was mistakenly addressed to you :)